# Which version of Taylor Theorem is this?

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Suppose $X$ is a random variable and $\psi(t)=E[\exp(itX)]$ is its characteristic function. Let $K(t)$ be the principal value of the logarithm of $\psi(t)$. Suppose further that $E(|X|^{r+2})<\infty$ for some integer $r\geq 0$.

Then, my [reading material](https://galton.uchicago.edu/~wichura/Stat304/Handouts/L19.edge.pdf) (the question is self-contained, link included for completeness) claims that the **Taylor's Theorm** implies
$$
K(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{r+2}\kappa_j\frac{(it)^j}{j!}+o(\tau^{r+2}),\quad t\in\mathbb{R},
$$
where
$$
\kappa_j=\frac{K^{(j)}(0)}{i^j},\quad j=0,\ldots,r+2,
$$
are the cumulants of $X$.

> **Question**: which version of Taylor's Theorem is this and where can I find its rigorous statement (and proof)? (preferred source: textbook)

I only know 2 verions of Taylor's Theorem: one deals with real functions of real variables (univariate or multivariate) and one deals with holomorphic functions. As $K$ may not have all of its derivatives, I don't think the latter applies.

Comment: If you take the remainder in integral form, or in the form $O(h^m)$ resp. $o(h^m)$, the Taylor theorem for real-valued functions of a real variable extends to complex-valued functions of a real variable (after all, a complex-valued function can be viewed as a pair of real-valued functions). It's that. (But if the moment-generating function exists in a neighbourhood of $0$, one could also use the version for holomorphic functions, since then $K$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$.)

Comment: In order to use Taylor’s theorem you have to show that that by your hypothesis $\psi$ is $r+2$ times differentiable. This in turn implies $K$ is $r+2$ Times differentiable. The version of Taylor’s theorem you use here is for functions from R to C. It works the same as for functions from R to R